# timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate or timeIntervalSince1970

Tags: objective-c, ios

Would there be an advantage to using timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate versus timeIntervalSince1970 (other than the fact that the ARM processor is 32 bit)?

Comment: Why would you care, are you calling that inside a loop?

Comment: Because I am sending it to a webserver to store in MySQL which uses the unix epoch starting in 1970 instead of starting in 2001. Sure, it's easy to convert (which I might just end up doing) but really shouldn't be a problem if ARM gets upgraded to 64 bit in the future

Comment: Am sending data to the a server to be stored, and i use timeIntervalSince1970 everything work good with me

Comment: It's currently using timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate....

Comment: Whichever one suits your needs.  You lose a few bits of precision using the 1970 reference for "now" dates, but the lost precision is in the microseconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I say as long as it's converted on the server side when using timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate it's fine. timeIntervalSince1970 would be an option as well since ARM might be upgraded to 64 bit before 2038.